# not forwarding or redirecting jsf

Tags: jsf, navigation, action

I have two pages for registration. On one I get the user data into a request scoped bean and on the next one I display the data gathered. On the second page there is a button to redirect the user to log in.

Here is the button action for the register.xhtml. The result of the regUser.register is reg_success, which is the name of the second page, where I display the user data.

```
        <p>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.regButtonText}" action="#{regUser.register}"/>
        </p>
```

In the reg_success.xhtml I have this code for the button:

```
        <p>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.regToLogin}" action="login"/>
        </p>
```

My login page has the name login.xhtml.

Even if I insert this navigation rule into my faces-config.xml the forward does not happen. Indeed from the register.xhtml the user is forwarded and the url does not change on the second page.

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/reg_success.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:commandButton>` only works when it's inside a `<h:form>`. See also the first point of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183).

But in this particular case you don't seem to need a POST request. Just use `<h:button>` then. This creates a GET request without the need for a `<h:form>`.

```
<h:button value="#{msgs.regToLogin}" outcome="login" />
```